# MS Access use VBA to export a Query to a single excel file with multi sheets

Tags: vba, ms-access, export-to-excel

I use access to count data and now I want to export it to a single excel file with multiple sheets.

In my Access I have a query like this.
This query is built from two table(combine some information together)

http://img.libk.info/f4.png

And I want to export it to a single excel file use the name column as sheet name

The output may look like this.

Each sheet only contain certain items.(A01 sheet only contain where name = A01)

http://img.libk.info/f5.png

Anyone has idea how to achieve this?

Look forward to your reply. Thanks@@!

Comment: You can probably loop through your data. Once the last name does not equal the newest selection then make a new sheet. A quick search came up with this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038691/exporting-data-into-excel-with-multiple-spreadsheets

Comment: you haven't posted any code so it's very difficult to understand what is your exact problem. Please not, stackoverflow isn't a free codewriting service, so we won't provide complete code for any problem. Please post what you've achieved so far and what is your particular problem. Quickest way is probably to run a query first to list only `name`, load it to an array, then use it as a criteria in your original query so you can copy the subqueries' output to different sheets.

Comment: @usselite: you mean I need to use EPPlus to make sheets?

Comment: I think maybe I may use this as a reference. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21251034/access-vba-sql-how-to-export-multiple-queries-into-one-excel-workbook-but

Answer (score 0):

I use this to export my query to excel.

Thank you all for replying!

```
Private Sub ExportExcel_Click()

    Dim sPath As String
    Dim RecordSt As Recordset
    Dim dBase As Database
    Dim stringSQL As String
    Dim doSQL As String
    Dim stDocName As String
    Dim rCnt As Integer

    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    sPath = Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\Test.xls"
    Set dBase = CurrentDb()
    stringSQL = "SELECT * FROM custom_query  GROUP BY Name;"


    Set RecordSt = dBase.OpenRecordset(stringSQL)
    SysCmd acSysCmdInitMeter, "working...", RecordSt.RecordCount
    For rCnt = 0 To RecordSt.RecordCount - 1
        SysCmd acSysCmdUpdateMeter, rCnt
        stDocName = RecordSt.Fields("Name").Value
        doSQL = "SELECT * INTO [" + stDocName + "] from custom_query where custom_query.Name=""" + stDocName + """;"
        DoCmd.RunSQL doSQL
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, stDocName, sPath, True
        DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, stDocName
        RecordSt.MoveNext
    Next rCnt
    SysCmd acSysCmdRemoveMeter

End Sub
```